# What can be mapped to the entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

What is the utility of the Microsoft Entity Framework? EF allows me to map entities to databases (tables). I it possible to map entities to other queryable system?

I think of web services, specific calls to other system, exe, files, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework is based on ADO.NET, so it can be used with anything that has an ADO.NET Data Provider.

Here is a link to the official ADO.NET Data Providers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx

If you wanted to use it with an exe or web service, you could if you wanted to go through the effort of creating an ADO.NET Data Provider.  However, this does not seem like a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: For me an entity is first of all a common container for all kind of data I can Create/Read/Update/Delete from any data system. Not only from a database... It can be a call that return a XML structure...

Comment: @DranDane That *almost* sounds like you're equating an **entity** being the same as an **active record** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework is an ORM (Object-Relational Mapper) so it's specifically meant to work against relational databases.

You can use still use LINQ (which is what I suspect you're really after) against other data providers like WCF, OData, etc.

Comment: From Wikipedia "In software engineering, an entity-relationship model (ER model for short) is an abstract and conceptual representation of data." It's says data and not relational databases.

Comment: @DranDane That's an ER model, which inevitably gets converted to the relational model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) used by databases. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, EF is an ORM for databases. You could hack together providers for "other queryable systems", but that's not what its designed for.

LINQ providers, however, such as LINQ to XML and LINQ to objects, allow you to query (but not write to) just about anything that can be represented as a collection.